# Advantages and disadvantages of dart shelf package for backend projects

Tags: database, flutter, dart, backend

I am building a multi platform application that works in different platforms like windows, ios, android and web by flutter

The problem is that i need to build a backend code that can handle authentication, storing files and folders and usual data so i need to know if dart shelf is meant for this type of projects and being secured or not

I really need something like advantages and disadvantages of the package and what can i do to do my backend code

I tried to do my project in aquaduct and found that the community doesn't support it any more so i really need to use shelf so what do u think?

Comment: Have you looked at Supabase?  Shelf is more about middleware, to provide a friendly customer-facing port which redirects it to the heavy lifting backend.  It can occasionally be the datastore as well, but I don't think that's where it shines.